# while adding .freetrans function, the contextmenu is not appering.

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, menu

i am using two jquery libraries in my page

1. jquery-free-transform (https://github.com/gthmb/jquery-free-transform)
2. jQuery-contextMenu (https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu)

while using .freetrans function from one library, the contextmenu function is not working from other library.

Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my_image").click(function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo(".block").addClass('default_width context-menu-one').freetrans();

    });
});
</script>   


<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $.contextMenu({
                    selector: '.context-menu-one',
                    callback: function(key, options) {
                        var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
                    },
                    items: {                    
                        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit", callback: function(key, opt){ alert("Foo!"); }},
                        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                       copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                        "sep1": "---------",
                        "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                            return 'icon icon-quit';
                        }}
                    }

                });

            });
        </script>
```

if i **remove** .freetrans() function from above script the below contextmenu function runs perfectly.. 
But i need both to be working in same time..
my main idea is the object is dragable, scalable, rotation and when i right click i can show some more options for that object.

Thanks in advance...